# list mean values of all possible column combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mean

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Value         Type       country   mean
-1.975767     Weather    Brazil
-0.540979     Fruits     China
-2.359127     Fruits     China
-2.815604     Corona     China
-0.712323     Weather    UK
-0.929755     Weather    Brazil
```

I want to calculate an overall mean value for all different combinations of Type & Country. For example:

the mean of Weather, Brazil would be = (-1.975767 -0.929755) / 2

Then I want to add these combinations to another table:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

```
country    type       mean     count
Brazil     Weather             2
Brazil     Corona              
China      Corona              1
China      Fruits              2
```

I can calculate the mean like this:

```
print(df.groupby(["type", "country"])["value"].mean())
```

but how do I save these values in a new df in the desired format?

Edit:
This works

```
df_new = df.groupby(["type", "country"], as_index = False)["value"].mean()
```

but then if I try to add a count in the same way:

```
df_new = df.groupby(["type", "country"], as_index = False).count()
```

it transposes all the cols instead of adding a count col after the mean col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as_index` parameter in your `groupby`:

```
df_new = df.groupby(["type", "country"], as_index = False)["value"].mean()
```

Then the result is a standard dataframe:

```
    type    country value
0   Corona  China   -2.815604
1   Fruits  China   -1.450053
2   Weather Brazil  -1.452761
3   Weather UK  -0.712323
```

**EDIT:** How can we add another column with the `count`? You can simply append a new column with the result of a new `groupby` like this:

```
# original answer
df_new = df.groupby(["type", "country"], as_index = False)["value"].mean().rename(columns={'value':'mean'})

# Add count also
df_new['count'] = df.groupby(["type", "country"])["value"].count().tolist()
df_new
```

Output:

```
type    country mean    count
0   Corona  China   -2.815604   1
1   Fruits  China   -1.450053   2
2   Weather Brazil  -1.452761   2
3   Weather UK  -0.712323   1
```

Comment: Is the `themes` column in the original dataframe? whar is it filled with?

Comment: This works but I can I add another "count" col in the same way? I tried this ```df_new = df.groupby(["type", "country"], as_index = False).count()``` but it transposes the columns

Comment: Yes, you can. There are multiple ways to do this and I added one of them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally speaking, I prefer JANO's answer, but here is what I came up with:

```py
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Value":[-1.23, -1.65, -0.123, -0.67, 2.456], "Type":["Weather", "Fruits", "Corona", "Corona", "Weather"], "country": ["Brazil", "China", "China", "Iran", "Iran"]})
resultDataframe = {"Value":[], "Type":[], "country":[]}
for country in dataframe["country"].unique():
  tempDataframe = dataframe[dataframe["country"] == country]
  a = tempDataframe.groupby(by="Type").mean().reset_index()
  for index, row in a.iterrows():
    resultDataframe["Value"].append(row["Value"])
    resultDataframe["Type"].append(row["Type"])
    resultDataframe["country"].append(country)
pd.DataFrame(resultDataframe)
```

|  | Value | Type | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -1.23 | Weather | Brazil |
| 1 | -0.123 | Corona | China |
| 2 | -1.65 | Fruits | China |
| 3 | -0.67 | Corona | Iran |
| 4 | 2.456 | Weather | Iran |